# Listing all users by their avatars in wordpress

Tags: avatar, gravatar

I want to list pictures of all avatars how do I do this

Comment: Do you know how to list the users? You'll just need to call [get_avatar()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/) or [get_avatar_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/) for each.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can jump start by using following example. Here I'll be listing users and loop through them to display avatar and display name.

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users();
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
    /* Here passing user email and avater size */
    echo get_avatar( $user->user_email , 96 );
    echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</span>';
}
```

Read more about

1. [get_users()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/)
2. [get_avatar()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar/)

Answer (score 4):

- You have to retrieve all users with this [get_users()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/) and loop through them.
- Then you have to get the avatar URL using a current user id with this [get_avatar_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_avatar_url/).

```
$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );

// Array of stdClass objects.
foreach ( $users as $user ) :

    $avatar = get_avatar_url( $user->ID );
    // If you want to retrieve specifc size image.
    // $avatar = get_avatar_url( $user->ID, array( 'size' => '300') );
        
    if ( $avatar ) :
      echo '<img src=" ' . esc_url( $avatar ) . ' " />';
    endif;

endforeach;
```